# Change all links at once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there any way i can change all links at once under option tag?
**For Example:**

```
<select size="1" name="links" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
<option value=" http://website.com/1001/">Blue</option>
</select><br>

 <select size="1" name="links" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
<option value=" http://website.com/2001/">Red</option>
</select><br>

<select size="1" name="links" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
<option value=" http://website.com/3001/">Green</option>
</select>
```

.... And so on around 100 links .
Now i want to change link **website.com** to **m.website.com** furthur link  remains same. Like m.website.com/1001 , m.website.com/1002

Comment: On an Event or what?

Comment: Use a selector - `$('option')`, [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), and `.val*()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
$(function(){ 
  $('select[name="links"] option').each(function(){
   var val=$(this).val();
   val=val.replace('http://','http://m.');
   $(this).val(val);
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qpumymjp/)

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to do this is just find and replace all instances of http://website.com/ with http://m.website.com/

If there are some instances you don't want to replace you can use a regex to match the text. Something like

Find

```
(<option value=" http:\/\/)(website)(\.com\/\d+\/">.*?<\/option>)
```

and replace with

```
$1m.website$3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('select[name="links"] option').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    val = val.replace('website.com', 'm.website.com');
    $(this).val(val);
  });
});
```